# Open new activity from public static class in android studio( menu > settings > preferences> activity)?

Tags: android

Friends,
I want to open a new activity from static method. But I am not able to access the xml file. I want to write code to call this contact.xml in xml folder of resources that contains.

```
    <Preference
    android:id="@+id/about_call"
    android:title="Contact The Developer"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_call"
    android:onClick="Activity_call"
    android:key="contact"
/>
```

Now I am struck at the java code of preferences in settings.java that contains the contact.xml access.

```
 @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public static class AboutFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.contact);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), settings.class));
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

At this stage the xml file shows the listview of action_call. Please help me here to write code that if i click the xml id:action_call, it should do something either call or open an activity.

Answer (score 0):

maybe u can try this

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

switch(item.getItemId)){
case R.id.about_call:
        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), settings.class));
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: No, it is not doing anything.

Comment: public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch(item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.home:
                    startActivity(new Intent(this.getActivity(), settings.class));
                    return true;

                case R.id.about_call:
                    startActivity(new Intent(this.getActivity(), settings.class));
                    return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

Comment: how if u add Intent intent = new Intent(); 
startActivity(this.getActivity, settings.class));

Comment: The Android studio is not showing any error but the intent function is not doing anything.

Comment: are u want to open fragment or??

Comment: I just want to open an activity.